# java script drop downs not working properly on live server

Tags: javascript

I have four drop downs on my registration page (Country,State,District,Tehsil) that are dependent on one another. all drop downs are properly working on my local server but when i put it on live server sometimes it is not working. can anyone give me solution for this.[image]

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: No. Not without any more information. What exactly goes wrong? Have you checked your console for any errors?

Comment: What exactly not working?

Comment: i will show you one drop down code...

Comment: function getTehsil(curr_dis_pk) {
 var tehsilList = '';
  if ($("#curr_dis_pk").val() != "") {
   $.ajax({
url: "getTehsilAccordingToDistrict?curr_dis_pk=" + curr_dis_pk,
dataType: "json",
async: false,
error: (function () {
alert("server_error");
}),
success: function (list) {
if (list != "") {
var str;
$.each(list, function (i, item) {
tehsilList += '<option value="' + item.tehsil_master_pk + '">' + item.tehsil_name + '</option>'
})
$("#curr_teh_pk").append(tehsilList);
} else {
$("#curr_teh_pk").val("");
alert("Tehsil not found.");}}});}}

Comment: when i click on country sometimes states are not load in drop down list or if states loads and when i click click on state sometimes districts are not loads in drop downs and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Is the database on your Local server same as the database on the Live server?